# Is there any better way for non-empty validation?

Tags: javascript, validation

I've been **validating input elements** to ensure each element *at-least* have some data and notify user, what field is to be filled. The way I'm doing is,

```
function validate()
{   
    var product_name  = document.getElementById('pname').value;
    var p_number      = document.getElementById('pnumber').value;
    var description   = document.getElementById('descr').value;

    if(product_name=="")
         {alert("Please fill Product Name");   return false;}
    else if(p_number=="")
         {alert("Please fill product Number"); return false;}
    else if(description=="")
         {alert("Please fill description");    return false;}
    else
         return true;

}
```

I'm feeling that this code is not optimum and need to be improved. You guys might have be experienced on this validation and have some tricks around. Please help me to do the same validation in a better way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? It would make your life a lot easier IMO. Here's a very popular validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: you can use html5 syntax also like <input type="text" id="txtInput" required="required" />  for that you don't need to write js code to validate non-empty fields

Comment: Thank you so much Sohil. Simplest ever! But will this work on all browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your validate function more generic so that it can be used for any number of fields. You should also use trim() to guard against empty spaces.

```
function validate(fields) {   
    for (var i = 0, l = fields.length; i < l; i++) {
        var field = document.getElementById(fields[i].id);
        if (field.value == null || field.value.trim() === '') {
            alert('Please fill in ' + fields[i].name);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then to validate, you would pass in the names and ids

```
var isValid = validate([
    { id: 'pname', name: 'Product Name' },
    { id: 'pnumber', name: 'Product Number' },
    { id: 'descr', name: 'Description' }
]);
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks lot... Impressive really. choosing you the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
function validate()

{   
    var product_name  = document.getElementById('pname').value;
    var p_number      = document.getElementById('pnumber').value;
    var description   = document.getElementById('descr').value;

    if((product_name.trim()).length == 0)
         {alert("Please fill Product Name");   return false;}
    else if((p_number.trim()).length == 0)
         {alert("Please fill product Number"); return false;}
    else if((description.trim()).length == 0)
         {alert("Please fill description");    return false;}
    else
         return true;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't make out what's changed?

Comment: The OP's code wasn't using `if (str.length == "") {}`, it was using `if (str == "") {}`. How is your code a significant improvement over this?

Comment: OOps... 
I ve used `if (str.length == 0) {}` instead of checking `if (str == "") {}`

Answer (score 0):

Here try this :

```
function validate()
{   
    var d = document;
    var byId = function( id ) { return d.getElementById( id ); };

    var product_name  = byId('pname').value;
    var p_number      = byId('pnumber').value;
    var description   = byId('descr').value;

    if(product_name=="")
         {alert("Please fill Product Name");   return false;}
    else if(p_number=="")
         {alert("Please fill product Number"); return false;}
    else if(description=="")
         {alert("Please fill description");    return false;}
    else
         return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim function remove whitespace from both sides of a string. It's used for validating the empty spaces in the field.

So try using this format

`if(product_name.trim().length == 0)`